# Adding Jquery/JS to input & Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add CSS to the label element if the input is selected

I have tried and failed using input:checked + label due to the way the html is built which i am unable to change.

Does any one know how i can do this using Javascript / Jquery or CSS?

```
<div class="radio-button-container">
    <div class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" value="QUARTER" name="frequency" id="frequencyQUARTER">
    </div>
    <div class="radio-label">
    <label for="frequencyQUARTER">New Label</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: `input:checked + label` combination will work if both the elements are sibling. Write for `change listener on `input` field and based on selection state, add or remove CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#frequencyQUARTER').change(function(){
    if($('#frequencyQUARTER').is(':checked')){

        $('.radio-label').find('label').css({color:'red'});
    }
    else{
        $('.radio-label').find('label').css({color:'yellow'});
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="radio-button-container">
    <div class="radio-button">
        <input type="radio" value="QUARTER" name="frequency" id="frequencyQUARTER">
    </div>
    <div class="radio-label">
    <label for="frequencyQUARTER">New Label</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d3u1ujvc/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the label for in the radio change event and apply the class accordingly.

Firstly remove the class to all the radio siblings element.

Code:

```
$(".radio-button-container input[type='radio']").on("change", function () {
    $(".radio-button-container input[type='radio']").each(function (i, e) {
        $("label[for='" + this.id + "'").removeClass("checked");
    });
    $("label[for='" + this.id + "'").addClass("checked");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5saLna0z/